# CNC Linux machine hangs when trying to acess a Windows shared folder

Tags: windows-7, linux, network-shares, samba

The CNC Linux machine hangs at this:

```
smb -s //NATS:192.168.0.201/FLEXICAM /flexicam/jobs/remote
```

I have Windows 7 on NATS as 192.168.0.201 and I can ping the other machine.

I think something is wrong with the shared folder. This may sound stupid but does the shared folder have to be a FLEXICAM folder with another sub folder flexicam/jobs/remote or is the 192.168.0.201/FLEXICAM the IP address and user name with shared folder flexicam/jobs/remote.

Not my forte but I have work to do and I am stuck.

Comment: `smb` is not part of standard Samba on Linux; could you explain what the command does or is supposed to do?